# Excel incorrect decimal calculation hundredths

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've come across a very strange issue pertaining to values entered with 2 decimal places (i.e. cents)

I want to express the hundredths as whole numbers -- so 2.01 entered would calculate to 1 (1 cent), 3.05 would calculate to 5 (5 cents).  Pretty simple I thought.

Well, I was using a formula =INT((A1-INT(A1))*100) which was working for 1.01, but not 2.01.  The value I end up with has to be a whole number (not just displayed as one), hence the extra INT around it.

In digging into this, I noticed that if you just enter 1.01 in a1, 1 in b1, then in c1 put the formula A1-b1, and then format that to 16 or more decimal places, it will show values that don't equal 0.0100000000000000 when a1 and b1 are changed.  If you change a1 to 2.01 and b1 to 2 it shows 0.0099999999999998 instead.  Why is Excel not handling the precision properly and adding all these decimal values to straightforward entered #s such as 2.01 - 2?  This occurs in Excel 2016 and Excel 2013 (at least).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/floating-point-arithmetic-inaccurate-result and https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/ perhaps, and similar pages. It's not incorrect calculation, it's a precision issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula:

```
=INT((A1-INT(A1))*100)
```

is working, but it may not give the value you expect.  Consider:

[image]

All looks good until **A22**.  It *appears* to be 2.01, but that's because it is formatted to 2 places.  The *actual* value is shown in the Formula Bar.

The formula operates on the Formula Bar value and returns the double zero following the decimal point.

You may prefer something like:

```
=ROUND((A22-INT(A22))*100,0)
```

which will give you 1.